# Printing '0' even if the number is bigger than 111

Tags: javascript

I have tried so many time to solve this question but I couldn't accomplish the expected outcome.
Here's the question in a nutshell:

> 1. Count all the values that are divisible by 11 in a given array
> 2. Return 0 if you encounter a number that is greater than or equal 111 regardless of the other divisible numbers of 11.
>
> For example:
>
> - Input: `[11,12,22,33]`
> - Output: `3`
> - Input: `[11,12,22,33,136]`
> - Output: `0`

I could solve the first part but failed with the second one.

Here is my code.

```js
function div(list) {
  let counter = 0
  list.forEach((value) => {
    if (value % 11 === 0) {
      counter++
      return counter
    }
    if(value>=111){
      return 0
    }
  })
  return counter
}

div([11, 22, 33, 44 , 116])

// OUTPUT : 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop instead so you can return inside if the break condition is found. Otherwise, return only at the end, not inside the loop.

```js
function div(list) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (const value of list) {
    if (value % 11 === 0) {
      counter++
    }
    if (value >= 111) {
      return 0
    }
  }
  return counter
}

console.log(div([11, 22, 33, 44, 116]));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but why forEach doesn't work like for loop.

Comment: Because all `return` does inside `forEach` is terminate the current iteration (and the value returned is ignored)

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers works great, adding a different approach, letting the inbuilt method do the looping

```
function div(total, value) {
  if (value % 11 === 0) {
      total++;
    }
    if(value>=111){
      total=0
    }
  return total;
}

console.log([11,12,22,33].reduce(div,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for...of` loop to iterate over list and return inside loop when value is >= 111, otherwise keep counting the values divisible by 11.

```js
function div(list) {
  let count = 0;
  for (const value of list) {
    if(value >= 111){
      return 0;
    } else if (value % 11 === 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(div([11, 22, 33, 44 , 116]));
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are great. Here's a solution that is a bit more condensed and offers a single return statement.

```js
function div(list) {
  let counter = 0;
  let oversized = false;
  for (let i = 0; (i < list.length) && !oversized; i++) {
     counter += (list[i] % 11) ? 0 : 1;
     oversized = (list[i] >= 111);
  }
  return oversized ? 0 : counter;
}

console.log(div([11, 22, 33, 44 ]));
```